# Adding child component on onClick of parent component again and again with new prop every time to child comp

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react so bear any nontechnical words. I have a parent component which has a button element on onClick of button a function is called which creates a new object. what I want is  also to happen when user clicks on this button child component should be renderd below parent button element and every time button is clicked new object should be passed as prop to child component so it can display it on screen, but previous called child should remain on screen.

import React from 'react';

```
class childcomponent extends React.PureComponent{
    state = { data: this.props.data }
        render(){
            return(
            <div>
                <span>Name: {this.state.data.name}</span>
                <span>Lastname: {this.state.data.lastname}</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

class Parentcomponent extends React.PureComponent{

```
handleAddChild=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
        //Here i form the object
        const user = {
        //key:value
        }
        //want to render child component from here
}

render(){
    return(
    <div>

    {/* //some code
    //some code
    //some code */}

    <button onClik={this.handleAddChild} >Save</button>

    {/* //want to render child component here </childcomponent> */}

    </div>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

here is a trick
make a state for children

```
this.state = {
 children: []
}
```

then loop to render

```
renderChildren = () => {
return this.state.children.map(item => {
   return <Child  />
})

}
```

and add children

```
handleAddChild=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
        //Here i form the object
        const user = {
        //key:value
        }
   this.setState({children: [...this.state.children, user]})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In react you will need to think in a way, that your JSX( html+js) is already prepared to display child component and only waits for state to display it. First of all, you will need state of parent component with some empty object
`state = { child: {} )`

then in you render method

```
{!!this.state.child && <Childcomponent data={this.state.child}}
```

then your add method

```
addChild = () => this.setState({ child: {name: 'Hi', surname: 'Hello'} })
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array in parent component and store the same as State value of the parent component,
pass this array as props to the child component
loop through the array in child component to make as much as list component

Child Component

`````
let List=this.props.data.map(item=>(
<div>
                <span>Name: {this.state.data.name}</span>
                <span>Lastname: {this.state.data.lastname}</span>
            </div>
))
        render(){
            return(
            <List/>
        )
    }
}````
`````

Answer (score 1):

Below is the working code for your question and [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-goldwasser-09wzb):-

App.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ChildComponent from "./Child";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: [
      { name: "name1", lastname: "lastname1", key: 1 },
      { name: "name2", lastname: "lastname2", key: 2 },
      { name: "name3", lastname: "lastname3", key: 3 }
    ],
    data: [],
    count: 0
  };
  handleAddChild = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      data: [...this.state.data, this.state.user[this.state.count]],
      count: this.state.count + 1
    });
  };
  render() {
    console.log("data", this.state.data);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.handleAddChild}>Save</button>
        {this.state.data.length &&
          this.state.data.map(item => {
            return <ChildComponent data={item} />;
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Child.js

```
import React from "react";

class childcomponent extends React.PureComponent {
  state = { data: this.props.data };
  render() {
    return (
      <div key={this.state.data.key}>
        <span>Name: {this.state.data.name}</span>
        <br />
        <span>Lastname: {this.state.data.lastname}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default childcomponent;
```

Hope that helps!!!